# Powershell replace non matching entries

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a powershell script that I am working on to edit some text files.  So far I have managed to extract all the lines I want to edit using select string, then with some help from an earlier post I have managed to remove all of the information on each line that I don't need.  What I want to do next is go through each line and remove any entries that do not match a particular string.  So for example, the text file may contain the following entries:

```
"1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2." "3.3.3.3" "4.4.4.4" "1.2.3.4"
"1.2.3.4" "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" "3.3.3.3" "4.4.4.4"
```

I want to strip out anything that isn't either "1.1.1.1" OR  "2.2.2.2" OR "3.3.3.3" OR "4.4.4.4"

- All the entries are within double quotes
- The entries that need to be removed may be located anywhere on the line.
- The entries that need tobe removed differ on each line
- The entries that need to stay are fixed

**Essentially, what I want to do is remove anything that does not match 1 of 6 possible fixed values and leave all other values unaffected.**

Thus far I've tried using get-content with -replace option, various forms of select-string, regex etc but so far no luck.  This is a little bit beyond my Powershell knowledge

EDIT:

**I think the original way I was trying wasn't the right way of going about it and perhaps I didnt phrase the question correctly.  I now have all the entries in a csv file, the output of which is similar to the below:**

```
1  : Dhcp
2  : Server
3  : 192.168.0.1
4  : Scope
5  : 192.168.0.10
6  : set
7  : optionvalue
8  : 6
9  : IPADDRESS
10 : 192.168.0.11    
11 : 192.168.0.12
12 : 192.168.0.13
13 : 192.168.0.14
14 : 192.168.0.15
15 : 192.168.0.16 
16 : 192.168.0.17
17 : 
18 : 
19 : 
20 :
```

**What I would like to do is go through the csv file, check the value of columns 10-16 for each entry, and delete any entries that do not match a predefined list.**

Answer (score 0):

You could compare each string to an array of acceptable values and perform whatever action accordingly.

$array = "1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3"

if ($array -notcontains $data ) { $data -replace ".","" }

Comment: the closing parenthesis of the condition is incorrect. And `-replace "*", ""` will never works

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
$a -replace  '\s*"1.1.1.1"\s*|\s*"2.2.2.2"\s*|\s*"3.3.3.3"\s*|\s*"4.4.4.4"\s*'
```

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the response, your solution is almost what I need...Using that code, I am able to remove all traces of 1.1.1.1 , 2.2.2.2 etc, but what I want to do is remove anything that is NOT 1.1.1.1 , 2.2.2.2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new array from all the matching lines, then set the file content to that new array.

You can change it to `-notmatch` if you wanted to create an array of everything that does not match.

```
$pattern = "1\.1\.1\.1|2\.2\.2\.2|3\.3\.3\.3|4\.4\.4\.4"
$file_path = "C:\text.csv"
$text_file = get-content $file_path
foreach ($line in $text_file) {
    if ($line -match $pattern) {
        $line += @($new_lines)
    }
$new_lines | set-content $file_path
}
```